Error: the command pytest could not be found within PATH
I am trying to run a suite using pytest with this command:
pytest -n8 --dc=us best_practice/desktop_web/
However, when I try to execute the run, I get the error:
Error: the command pytest (from best-practice-desktop-us) could not be found within PATH.
I verified it's installed by running pip list and I see it listed in their as a package:
I attempted adding it to my path with this line but that didn't work either:
export PATH="/Users/mikejones/Library/Python/3.12/lib/python/site-packages/pytest:$PATH" 
This is the repo I am attempting to run. It should work so it's clearly an issue where my terminal can't access the directory containing pytest.
Anyone know what to do to resolve this?

The pytest above is a directory rather than an executable. Look for a pytest executable, possibly in the same directory as python, pylint and others

try to run it like this: python -m pytest -n8 --dc=us best_practice/desktop_web/
